# Data disappearing when date clicked or month changes

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using [VanillaCalendar](https://vanilla-calendar.pro/docs/learn/getting-started/installation) to show events listed on certain days

You can see my full demo in the code snippet below or [here on CodePen](https://codepen.io/OnTheWeb/pen/gOZNzYz)

How it works is I have a loop that runs through some JSON data and appends a div onto days that have events. It looks like this :

```
const assignEventsToCalendar = function() {
  let eventData = data;
  for (const {month, days} of eventData) {
    for (const {day, events} of days) {
      const key = day.split('-').map(p => p.padStart(2, '0')).join('-');
      let dayElement = document.querySelector(`[data-calendar-day="${key}"]`);
 
      if (dayElement) { // only apply flair if day exists (is in current month)
        let eventWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        eventWrapper.classList.add("event-wrapper");
        dayElement.append(eventWrapper);

        for (const {title, category} of events) {
          let singleEvent = document.createElement("div");
          singleEvent.classList.add("event", category);
          eventWrapper.append(singleEvent);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The problem is that if you click on a day or change month by clicking on the month at the top - the event markers on the days disappear so you can no longer see which events are on which days

Using the [VanillaCalendar](https://vanilla-calendar.pro/docs/learn/getting-started/installation) event to run the function when the month arrows are clicked seems to work for repopulating the events, but there isn't an event for every action

```
actions: {
  clickArrow(e, self) {
    setTimeout(assignEventsToCalendar, 1000);
  }
}
```

Is there a way I could do this with JS?

**Code Snippet**

```js
let data = [{"month":"2024-2","days":[{"day":"2024-2-15","events":[{"title":"Event One","category":["Category1"]}]},{"day":"2024-2-21","events":[{"title":"Event Two","category":["Category2"]},{"title":"Event Three","category":["Category1"]}]},{"day":"2024-2-20","events":[{"title":"Event Four","category":["Catgory2"]}]}]},{"month":"2024-3","days":[{"day":"2024-3-2","events":[{"title":"Event Five","category":["Category1"]}]},{"day":"2024-3-23","events":[{"title":"Event Six","category":["Category2"]}]}]}];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // console.log('data.month', data.month);
  var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

  var options = {
    date: {
      min: "1920-01-01",
      max: "2038-12-31"
    },
    settings: {
      range: {
        min: currentDate
      },
      visibility: {
        disabled: true,
        theme: 'light'
      }
    },
    actions: {
      clickArrow(e, self) {
        setTimeout(assignEventsToCalendar, 1000);
      }
    }
  };

  var calendar = new VanillaCalendar("#calendar", options);
  calendar.init();

  assignEventsToCalendar();

});

const assignEventsToCalendar = function() {
  let eventData = data;
  for (const {
      month,
      days
    } of eventData) {
    for (const {
        day,
        events
      } of days) {
      const key = day.split('-').map(p => p.padStart(2, '0')).join('-');
      let dayElement = document.querySelector(`[data-calendar-day="${key}"]`);

      if (dayElement) { // only apply flair if day exists (is in current month)
        let eventWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        eventWrapper.classList.add("event-wrapper");
        dayElement.append(eventWrapper);

        for (const {
            title,
            category
          } of events) {
          let singleEvent = document.createElement("div");
          singleEvent.classList.add("event", category);
          eventWrapper.append(singleEvent);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
#calendar {
  max-width: 350px;
}

.vanilla-calendar-day__btn {
  .event-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: auto;
  }
  .event {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    &.Category1 {
      background-color: red;
    }
    &.Category2 {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>


<!-- Vanilla Calendar -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/vanilla-calendar.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/vanilla-calendar.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/themes/light.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pop-ups](https://vanilla-calendar.pro/docs/learn/customization-and-modification/popups) feature to mark specific dates with CSS classes and add custom HTML pop-ups to them on hover.

If you specifically want boxes/divs/whatever to mark the days, one option is to use [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to create a pseudo-element and set the content to an emoji/mess around with the pseudo-element's CSS properties to make whatever you want:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // console.log('data.month', data.month);
  var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

  var options = {
    date: {
      min: "1920-01-01",
      max: "2038-12-31"
    },
    settings: {
      range: {
        min: currentDate
      },
      visibility: {
        disabled: true,
        theme: 'light'
      }
    },
    popups: {
      '2024-02-15': {
        modifier: 'event',
        html: 'Event One<br/>Event Two',
      },
      '2024-02-27': {
        modifier: 'event',
        html: 'Event One<br/>Event Two',
      }
    }
  };

  var calendar = new VanillaCalendar("#calendar", options);
  calendar.init();

});
```

```css
#calendar {
  max-width: 350px;
}

.event:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>


<!-- Vanilla Calendar -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/vanilla-calendar.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/vanilla-calendar.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/themes/light.min.css">
```